# xslt 1.0 how to replace empty or blank value with 0 (zero) in select condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:call-template name="SetNetTemplate">
<xsl:with-param name="xyz" select="$node1value
                                 + $node2value
                                 + $node3value
                                 - $node4value
                                 - $node5value
                                 - $node6value"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

If nodevalue is empty or blank, i want to replace that value with 0 (zero).
   Problem is that in this calculation if any nodevalue is empty or blank, it is giving NaN       result. e.g. select "10-2+5-2- -4"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:with-param name="xyz" select="translate(number($node1value), 'aN', '0')
                                 + translate(number($node2value), 'aN', '0')
                                 + translate(number($node3value), 'aN', '0')
                                   ...
                                 - translate(number($node6value), 'aN', '0')"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

Note that the above is just a "cute trick" designed to avoid the verbosity of the proper and straightforward solution that would do this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number($node1value)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$node1value" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="0" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

to each and every one of your operands before trying to treat them as numbers.

Comment: Think you've missed a 0 in the translate: `translate(number($node1value), 'aN', '00')` - need the extra 0 to match the N in aN.

Comment: @Barney No, there is nothing missing here. The idea is to replace the "a" in "NaN" (not "aN") with a 0 and remove the two "N" characters - so that the end result is a single 0 character. Your version would have returned "000".

Comment: Right - I get it. Yep, my version did indeed return '000', which is still zero, but not as neat as yours.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<xsl:with-param name="xyz" select="concat(0, $node1value)
                                 + concat(0, $node2value)
                                 + concat(0, $node3value)..."/>
```

etc

Comment: I don't want to concatenate 0 to my number. I want to replace nodevalue with 0 if that is empty or blank.

Comment: @ManishMawatwal I am afraid you are missing the point here: adding a 0 to the left of the value will result in 0 if the value is empty (which is what you want), and should have no effect when the value contains a number. That is unless that number is negative - in which case this will totally bomb (no pun intended, but it's nice to have one anyway).

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
number(concat('0',$nodeValue))
```

Comment: This is practically the same answer as the one given above by Michael Kay - and with the same limitation.