# How to retrieve an unknown number of elements from a complex type in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsd-validation

This is kind of confusing to word so suppose I have the following in a xsd file (sorry for the poor format or errors, wrote this on the fly):

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="Family">
       <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Person" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          <xsd:element name="Pets" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element name="Dogs" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                   <xsd:element name="Cats" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                   <xsd:element name="Reptiles" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                         <xsd:sequence>
                             <xsd:element name="Snakes" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                             <xsd:element name="Lizards" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                         <xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                   </xsd:element>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

and suppose I have an xml file that's an instance of this:

```
...
<Family>
    <Person>Father</Person>
    <Person>Mother</Person>
    <Person>Son</Person>
    <Pets>
       <Reptiles>
           <Snakes>2</Snakes>
       <Reptiles>
    </Pets>
</Family>
<Family>
    <Person>Father</Person>
    <Person>Mother</Person>
    <Person>Son</Person>
    <Person>Daughter</Person>
    <Pets>
         <Dogs>1</Dogs>
    </Pets>
</Family>
<Family>
    <Person>Father</Person>
    <Person>Mother</Person>
    <Person>Daughter</Person>
    <Pets>
         <Cats>3</Cats>
    </Pets>
</Family>
<Family>
    <Person>Father</Person>
    <Person>Mother</Person>
    <Person>Son</Person>
    <Person>Daughter</Person>
    <Pets>
         <Dogs>2</Dogs>
         <Cats>3</Cats>
         <Reptiles>
             <Lizards>3</Lizards>
         </Reptiles>
    </Pets>
</Family>
...
```

And I was to create an xsl file using xsl stylesheet using `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">`that will display this information in a table when it is transformed into html. Since each family's information is different how would I proceed to create a table that holds all the information? The table would look something like this: 
[image]
More specifically how would I use `xsl:for-each` and elements of xsl like that to come up with that table especially since there are optional elements and you don't know the how the family is made before hand?

EDIT: Had to redo table from "Reptiles" to "Snakes" "Lizards"

EDIT: Here is the example xsl file I am trying to work on

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body>
        <h1>Family Information</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="yellow">
                <td><b>People</b></td>
                <td><b>Dogs</b></td>
                <td><b>Cats</b></td>
                <td><b>Snakes</b></td>
                <td><b>Lizards</b></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Family">
                 <tr style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: verdana">

                 //How do I get the attribute values here?

                 </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </table>
   <body><html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
...
```

Comment: So I can make the headers "People, Dogs, Cats, Snakes, Lizards" just fine but once I get to the second row and actually extracting the attribute info for each element, that's where I get stuck.

Comment: Ok I've added an example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why your `xsl:for-each` with the "Family" select didn't work is because the context node was wrong. The template selected the document node `/` which didn't have `Family` elements as children (because there is only one root node allowed in XML). So the `xsl:for-each` tried to iterate over an empty set.

To fix this, I added a root node named `<root>` that wraps the `<Family>` elements. So the sample XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="transform.xslt" type="text/xsl" ?>
<root>
  <Family>
    ...
  </Family>
  <Family>
    ...
  </Family>
  ...
</root>
```

Now, you can access the `<Family>` elements with the following template which yields the desired result:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html><body>
        <h1>Family Information</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="yellow">
                <td><b>People</b></td>
                <td><b>Dogs</b></td>
                <td><b>Cats</b></td>
                <td><b>Snakes</b></td>
                <td><b>Lizards</b></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Family">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:for-each select="Person"><xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if></xsl:for-each></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="translate(number(Pets/Dogs),'aN','0')" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="translate(number(Pets/Cats),'aN','0')" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="translate(number(Pets/Reptiles/Snakes),'aN','0')" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="translate(number(Pets/Reptiles/Lizards),'aN','0')" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </table>
   </body></html>
</xsl:template>
```

The `translate(number(Pets/...),'aN','0')` is a clever XSLT-1.0 way [described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018753/1305969) which replaces the string `NaN`(Not a Number) with a `0`. This is useful if the element given does not exist.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add a root mybad. But that second part is what I was looking for! For my actual homework (not the example in this code) there are so many children nested and optional attributes but I had no idea how to google what I wanted to do. Thank you for the help man. Truly appreciated. Does the NaN thing only work for `type=xsd:int`?

Comment: So what if Person was also a complex type with elements `<FirstName>` and `<LastName>` and I wanted to get each set of names (ex. John Smith, Jerry Jr., etc.) instead of just `Father, Mother, Son, etc.`>

Comment: The `number(...)` function atttempts to convert the given input/string to a number. If that doesn't work, it outputs NaN ("Not a Number"). Concerning your second question: Try replacing `<xsl:value-of select="." />` in the inner `xsl:for-each` with `<xsl:value-of select="concat(FirstName,' ',LastName)" />` or something like this.